# Turn on 'window compositing'?

Tags: compiz

On the google hangounts support board it says:

> Issues screen sharing on Linux devices.
>
> If you are having trouble screen sharing on Linux, please check that
>   window compositing is enabled.

I am having issues screensharing on my ubuntu 12.04. How can I turn this on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Compiz doesn't work well on your computer, you can always try to enable Metacity's compositing manager. To do this, press Ctrl+Alt+T (opens a terminal window), then run `gconf-editor`. On the left side, browse to apps > metacity > general, then check the box corresponding  to `compositing_manager` on the right.

**[EDIT]:** Visual help to configuration manager:

1. Open dash and type Config on the search field. Proceed to selecting configuration editor.[image: Open conf editor]
2. After you have opened the configuration editor, browse to apps > metacity > general, then check the box corresponding  to `compositing_manager` on the right, like this (my mouse pointer shows the box you should check):
   [image: Compositing manager]

Hope this helped.

Comment: Thanks - I went to Appearance (via System Settings, I don't have System Preferences)  but it looks like this: http://i.imgur.com/YDF7Q.png No "Visual Effects" tab at all?  gconf-editor is not found btw. I assume I need to sudo apt get something for it?

Comment: No, I do not think you need to download something, just open Dash, and type in the search field Configuration and from the results select configuration editor. I will post some screenshots in my answer case you won't find it.

Comment: Zilch. Only thing that returns searching for "configuration" is some code files from some projects I've been on.

Comment: Just in case, why don't you open a terminal, and type sudo apt-get install gconf-editor?